Is there a way to make this if statement only run once?
I am trying to make a script that gives the player 5 lives for every 100 points. It works, however a bit too well. When I run the code, when i reach 100 points, it doesn't stop giving lives, and only stops when I get more points.
This is the code I'm using:
def increase_lives():
    global lives
    global score
    global extralives
    
    if score % 100 == 0 and score != 0 or keyboard.lctrl and keyboard.ralt:
        extralives = 1
    if extralives == 1:
        lives += 5
        extralives -= 1

I am using Thonny with PyGame and PGZero. Any help is greatly appreciated.

You need an additional global variable to store for which score you already gave lives. Only if new score is larger add more lives.

Why are global variables evil? - You should probably refactor your code to use a (data)class or something like that. Also, please provide a [mre] that shows an example of this problem occurring - it makes testing much easier for answers.

You can create a temp variable to mark a "milestone".
global lives
global score
global extralives
global milestone

if (score % 100 == 0 and score != 0 and score != milestone) or (keyboard.lctrl and keyboard.ralt):
    extralives = 1
    milestone = score
if extralives == 1:
    lives += 5
    extralives -= 1


I'm no expert, but I think you should use some flag to limit it for one time.
